# CICS Error Unable to create connection mainframe system

Tags: cics

One of my applications is integrated with the mainframe system. Through CICS / CTG. I am facing an error while executing a request.also, i have used ASN1 encoding for request

The error I am getting while executing the request

```
com.ibm.connector2.cics.CICSUserInputException: CTG9627E IOException occurred when writing to the Output Record

org.springframework.dao.NonTransientDataAccessResourceException: Unable to create a connection to the remote application; nested exception is com.ibm.connector2.cics.CICSUserInputException: 
CTG9627E IOException occurred when writing to the Output Record


com.ibm.connector2.cics.CICSUserInputException: CTG9627E IOException occurred when writing to the Output Record
        at com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIManagedConnection.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIConnection.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIInteraction.execute(Unknown Source)


java.io.IOException: messagelength in header greater than existing data length - common area too short?
       at com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIManagedConnection.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIConnection.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.ibm.connector2.cics.ECIInteraction.execute(Unknown Source)
```

i am using
`cics version : c900-20160704-0205`

Does anyone have any insights about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue with the below resolution

`messagelength in header greater than existing data length - common area too short?` as per this error message length is short so I have tried to increase length in a common area as per this documentation  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/5.6?topic=applications-transferring-data-between-programs-using-channels

added code in `CTG Service executor >> CTG Record`

```
setCommonAreaLength(32500)
```

After applying this resolution issue is resolved

Hope some one helps this ans

Answer (score 0):

Error description is available at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-tg-multi/9.0?topic=SSZHFX_9.0.0/cclaj/CTG9627E.htm

It seems like the data you are passing is not a isntanceof javax.resource.cci.Streamable.  Could you verify that.

Comment: Already checked with error information. and the data passes with the same code another CICS integration is working fine only all have the same requests and headers one of these has faced this error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).